# sqlplus to Access Syntax Issue

Tags: ms-access, syntax, oracle11g, syntax-error, sqlplus

I am unable to find an answer that has helped me resolve this issue. I am part of an organization at my university which requires our students to meet attendance criteria per our required meetings each semester. To track whether our students are meeting this criteria or not I want to create a report that will show me a list of all students who have missed any required meetings and how many meetings they have missed between a dates x and y.

The following query I wrote works fine when I run it through sqlplus

```
SELECT s.first_name, s.last_name, s.email, COUNT (A.student_mnumb) AS Attendance_Count 
FROM student_attendance A
INNER JOIN student S
ON S.student_M=A.student_Mnumb
INNER JOIN event E
ON e.event_name=a.event_name1
WHERE e.event_date>'01-AUG-13'
AND e.event_date<'01-DEC-13'
AND e.student_req='Y'
AND a.attend='N'
GROUP BY s.first_name, s.last_name, s.email
HAVING COUNT (A.student_mnumb) > 0;
```

However, when I enter this query into Access I receive the following error: "syntax error (missing operator) in query expression 'S.student_M=A.student_mnumb INNER JOIN event E ON e.event_name=a.event_name'.

My database is hosted through Oracle 11gxe and I am running an ODBC to create the reports on MS Access 2007. I have tried the same query with updated table titles per the ODBC account name (Student becomes BAP_Student) and the issue persists.

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your query works in Oracle already, you could create an Access "pass through" query which asks Oracle directly to give you back the results from that query.  That way wouldn't need to convert the query from Oracle to Access SQL.

Or even simpler, create an Oracle view based on that query.  Then from Access, create an ODBC link to the view.

If you do need to convert to Access SQL, the db engine requires parentheses for queries which include more than one `JOIN`.

```sql
FROM
    (student_attendance A
    INNER JOIN student S
    ON S.student_M=A.student_Mnumb)
    INNER JOIN event E
    ON e.event_name=a.event_name1
```

A change like that should get you past the first syntax error.  However, I encourage you to use Access' query designer to set up your joins.  It knows about the rules for parentheses which keep the db engine happy, and can handle that detail for you.

You may encounter other issues.  For example, Access uses `#` characters to delimit Date/Time values.  So, if Access sees the `event_date` field as Date/Time type, try something like this in your `WHERE` clause ...

```sql
    e.event_date > #2013-08-01#
AND e.event_date < #2013-12-01#
```